# selenium WebDriver, work without any internet browser.

Tags: java, selenium, httprequest, selenium-webdriver, httpresponse

I have simple selenium's  class. it works very well. Now i'm interested in, how to do the same sing in console mode. In the other words. I need a result (in the code, if request was succeeded or not.) I don't need to show in a web browser. if everything is well i need a return value, if not another return value (something like true or false);

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

 WebDriver driver;
 WebElement loginInput;
 WebElement passwordInput;
 WebElement loginSubmit;
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();     

 driver.get("URL");
 loginInput = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));

 loginInput.sendKeys("ninotyesh");
 passwordInput =driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
 passwordInput.sendKeys("key");
 loginSubmit = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
 loginSubmit.click();
```

Comment: In the Other words, I'm trying to do something like brute force (with list of users and passwords), it's for testing only. its for testing, otherwise I would used any script written in C++ or something like that :-)

Answer (score 5):

You might consider running your script in `HTMLUnitDriver` - see [short help](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) about it

And at end of your code I would do check for some element which should be present after successful login and print out TRUE in case the driver finds it.

Comment: Pavel Janicek
and is this being don without a browser?

Comment: and can you give me simple example. similar that i have done above?

Comment: @VakhoQoroglishvili Just replace `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` with `driver = new HTMLUnitDriver();`. It runs in memory using HTMLUnit, a Java-written in-memory browser. No browser window is popped. If that doesn't work for you, you could try [Phantom JS Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) which uses Phantom JS (an in-memory WebKit based browser).